# How to change an icon in the view using an if statement?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use the Ionic Framework and AngularJS and I want to show a specific icon when a task has been completed and a different icon when it has not been completed.

My code:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="task in tasks" class="item-icon-right" ng-class="{complete: task.completed}"
            ng-click="task.completed = !task.completed">
    <i class="material-icons">check_box_outline_blank</i>
    <i class="material-icons">check_box</i>
    {{task.title}}
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive delete" ng-click="tasks.splice($index, 1)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i>
    </ion-option-button>
    <ion-option-button class="" ng-click="edit(task)"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></ion-option-button>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. But you can use `ng-model="task.completed"` for your checkbox or `ng-checked="task.completed"` to have it checked or unchecked depending on state

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where in your code you would like this to happen, but if I have to guess, you could change the following two lines:

```
<i class="material-icons">check_box_outline_blank</i>
<i class="material-icons">check_box</i>
```

To the following:

```
<i class="material-icons">{{task.completed ? 'check_box':'check_box_outline_blank'</i>
```

The above is basically a short version of an if statement, I personally prefer to put these statements in a controller. So instead of putting the statement in the view, I would do the following:

```
<i class="material-icons" ng-class="getTaskIcon(task.completed)"></i>
```

And then in the controller:

```
$scope.getTaskIcon = function(taskCompleted) {
  if(taskCompleted == true) {
    return 'check_box'
  } else {
    return 'check_box_outline_blank'
  }
}
```

This may not work out of the box, but should point you in the right direction.